# Understanding connections and conversions of Avro in Apache Flume

Tags: avro, flume

I'm studying Apache Flume, but I can't understand a few things.
When a source/sink type is avro, does this mean that the event is sent in avro format?

That is, my data are encapsulated into flume event and this sent from sink to source in avro format. The [documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html) says:

> A Flume event is defined as a unit of data flow having a byte payload and an optional set of string attributes. A Flume agent is a (JVM) process that hosts the components through which events flow from an external source to the next destination (hop).

Does this mean that it does not make sense have an avro source at the top of the flow nor an avro sink at the end of the flow?

Does this mean that it makes sense have avro sink only when comes first an avro source (then have an avro source only the comes after an avro sink)?

Thank you to who will answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having an Avro source, then it opens a network port that is designed to accept Avro bytes.

Data you send into it should already be Avro, it is not converted for you.

The sink, on the other hand, takes the internal "Flume event" object structure and will convert to Avro format. The AvroSink requires a network port to attach to, which happens to support the input format for the server started by the Avro Source.

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#setting-multi-agent-flow

If you wanted to use a different type of source and translate to Avro on the fly, you'd use the Morphine interceptor or Avro Event Serializer

Comment: Rather than running a Flume agent on each server, though, it's far more scalable to run Kafka brokers and let application log directly to Kafka topics. Avro being optional

Comment: I think I got the answer after I have written this question. So the answer I've given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51935889/4047600 is correct, right?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Though, as mentioned, it's possible to setup interceptors/serializers to convert between formats

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your time cricket_007!